# Android gallery, Connected devices list, How are they connected?

Tags: gallery

I have Android Jelly Bean 4.2,  When I open Gallery, Select the sort list (top left) it lists "connected devices", there are three devices connected currently,  I am using a company wireless network connection (cell is poor inside here). I have not enabled any devices to connect in my Settings, Connect and share, everything is disabled or prompt. I do not understand how any devices could be connected?

Thanks, wrmcnut

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Are you the author of "Gallery"?

Comment: Perhaps those 'connected' devices are DLNA-enabled devices on the same network as yours?